# Silverlight 5 Hyperlink Change style BasedOn same base style but different foreground

Tags: hyperlink, silverlight-5.0, radix, foreground

I am trying to set a different style to a hyperlink control. The new style is BasedOn the same base style as the previous style which was set to the control and Foreground property has been overridden to a new color.
But on application the foreground does not change.

Few notes:
If the overriding property is FontSize, things seem to work fine.
In Silverlight 4, things worked fine.
If I remove the BasedOn property (dont derive from base class) things work fine.
First time setting of style is working but subsequent attemps to change style isnt working.
If I duplicate the style and change the foreground color, things work fine.
*Things work fine = foreground changing correctly.

**Base Style:**

```
<Style TargetType="HyperlinkButton" x:Key="NormalHyperlinkStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource DataGridFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BaseColor4}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource AccentColor}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Underline" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFA0A0A0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)" To="1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <StackPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="contentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Underline" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}" Margin="0,1,0,2" Opacity="0" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0" Opacity="0" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource FocusVisualStrokeThickness}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Derived Style:**

```
<Style x:Key="ToolbarHyperlinkSelectedStyle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource NormalHyperlinkStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
</Style>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
        selectedButton.Style =
            (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ToolbarHyperlinkSelectedStyle"];
```